Why are implicit coercions applied inconsistently here?
I'm confused about type coercions! The docs page says:

Coercion is allowed between the following types: ~snip~ Function item types to fn pointers

And the rustonomicon page says:

Note that we do not perform coercions when matching traits

In the code below, I therefore expect fn_vec and fn_tuple_vec to compile without explicit casts, but I don't understand why fn_iter compiles and also given that it does, why fn_tuple_iter does not. I'm assuming there's some simple explanation for this that I'm missing...
fn a() {}
fn b() {}

fn fn_vec(_: Vec<fn()>) {}
fn fn_iter(_: impl IntoIterator<Item=fn()>) {}
fn fn_tuple_vec(_: Vec<(fn(),)>) {}
fn fn_tuple_iter(_: impl IntoIterator<Item=(fn(),)>) {}

#[test]
fn test() {
    fn_vec(vec![a, b]); // compiles
    fn_iter(vec![a, b]); // compiles
    fn_tuple_vec(vec![(a,), (b,)]); // compiles
    fn_tuple_iter(vec![(a as fn(),), (b as fn(),)]); // compiles

    fn_tuple_iter(vec![(a,), (b,)]); // does not compile!
}


I add the same problem here. Type inference is not very deep. In your examples, this works when only one coercion has to be performed. In the last case, there is the fn pointer coercion you mention and the into_iter; that's one too many.
